# How to inherit from ABC and another class

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, python-3.8

I have a class

```py
class A(ABC):
  @abstractmethod
  def m():
    pass
```

and a bunch of classes inheriting from it.

```
class M1(A):
  ...

class M2(A):
  ...

...
```

Some of these have a lot in common as they share a lot of functionality such that I would like to introduce a common base class which itself inherits from `A`, but it does not introduce any new `@abstractmethod` methods:

```
       A
       |
  +----+----+
  |    |    |
  M1   M2   B
            |
         +--+--+
         |     |
         K1   K2
```

What should the definition for `class B` look like?

I'm on Python 3.8

**EDIT:** I am specifically asking as PyCharm tells me "B must inherit all abstract methods"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use

```
class B(A):
   pass
```

or any other code that is common to all children, but without `m`. This will still be abstract due to the absence of `m`.

---

An alternative is to use

```
class B(A, ABC):
   pass
```

In my opinion this is less good. This states that `B` is both an `A` and an `ABC`, while the former alternative states that `B` is an `A`, and it is an `ABC` insofar as much as `A` is an `ABC` itself.

Consider the case where you decide later on that `A` is not an `ABC` after all. For `M1` and `M2`, no change needs to be made. For `B`, you now need to remove its being an `ABC` as well. While making sure that `A` and `B` are synchronized in subclassing `ABC` is not a huge overhead in terms of code maintenance, I think it does indicate that the design is problematic, PyCharm's warning about the former alternative notwithstanding (I would suppress it as a false-positive).

Comment: Maybe I am just spoiled by PyCharm - it complains that `B` "must inherit all abstract methods" so I thought I should better indicate that this class is _also_ an ABC. Should I simply ignore this warning?

Comment: @scravy I think so. It's been filed at PyCharm as a false positive: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-16132

Comment: In the referenced issue the subclass `Mixin` that is abstract is expxlicitly marked as such (in a python 2.7 way). My class is not marked in any way. I know that the class is _effectively_ abstract and it behaves as such (can not be instantiated for example) but it is not marked as such. In other languages I'd have to explicitly mark it as abstract and looking at it I indeed think it would be good to signal the intent of this class actually being abstract. Let me rephrase my question: Would it hurt if additionally to `A` I'd also mixin `ABC`? `class B(A, ABC)`

Comment: @scravy I updated the answer to both address the question at the end of your comment, as well as to explain why I think the PyCharm issue to which I linked has a similar underlying principle.

Comment: @scravy: Just ignore it. Disable the warning if possible. Inheriting from `ABC` doesn't even make a class abstract, and the more places you stick `ABC` into the inheritance graph, the more likely you are to run into MRO issues. (I personally avoid `ABC` entirely and use the `ABCMeta` metaclass, which does the real work - `ABC` is just a way to trigger the `ABCMeta` metaclass for people less comfortable with metaclasses.)

Answer (score 1):

In your specific case you don't need to mix in anything. I don't personally use Pycharm, but creating `B` as a subclass of `A` works just fine and python won't complain.

```py
>>> from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
>>> class A(ABC):
...     @abstractmethod
...     def m(self):
...         pass
... 
>>> class B(A):
...     def common_method(self) -> str:
...         return 'b'
... 
>>> class K1(B):
...     def m(self) -> str:
...         return 'k1'
... 
>>> class K2(B):
...     def m(self) -> str:
...         return 'k2'
... 
>>> k1 = K1()
>>> k2 = K2()
>>> k1.m()
'k1'
>>> k2.m()
'k2'
>>> k1.common_method()
'b'
>>> k2.common_method()
'b'
>>> # However you can't do this
>>> b = B()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class B with abstract methods m
```

In case you have a different but similar structure (not the question directly but still relevant)

```
       A        <----- this is not abstract
       |
  +----+----+
  |    |    |
  M1   M2   B   <------ you want this to be abstract and also group some
            |           functionality for K1 and K2
         +--+--+
         |     |
         K1   K2
```

You can do it without mixing classes by defining the `metaclass` instead of subclassing `ABC` and `A` as a mixin (the metaclass does all the work anyways). Here is how you can do it.

```py
>>> from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod
>>> class A:
...     def m(self) -> str:
...         return 'a'
... 
>>> class B(A, metaclass=ABCMeta):
...     @abstractmethod
...     def n(self):
...         pass
...     def common_method(self) -> str:
...         return 'b'
... 
>>> class K1(B):
...     def n(self) -> str:
...         return 'k1'
... 
>>> class K2(B):
...     def n(self) -> str:
...         return 'k2'
... 
>>> k1 = K1()
>>> k2 = K2()
>>> k1.m()
'a'
>>> k2.m()
'a'
>>> k1.n()
'k1'
>>> k2.n()
'k2'
>>> k1.common_method()
'b'
>>> k2.common_method()
'b'
>>>
```